# Image Viewer with multiple selections on 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: image-viewers

In previous versions of Ubuntu I could select multiple images and view them in a single Image Viewer window.  In 18.04.1 it seems that a separate window/task is created for each selected image.  Is there any way to get the old behavior of viewing multiple selected images with a single Image Viewer instance?

Comment: Do you want to see the images side by side or view them one by one (in the same window)?

Comment: @sudodus My question is specifically for one by one in the same window, but you've now also got me interested in the former.

Comment: If you start Eye of Gnome, `eog`, and click on the icon with three horizontal lines, you can select Open... , get a window with files and directories, and then mark a few files. Click on Open and the files you selected will be the only files that you can view in the `eog` window.

Comment: @sudodus That works. I'll accept if you create an answer for that.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211087/software-to-seamlessly-edit-multiple-images/1292048#1292048

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### View files one by one in one single window

If you start Eye of Gnome, `eog`, and click on the icon with three horizontal lines, you can select Open... , get a window with files and directories, and then mark a few files. Click on Open and the files you selected will be the only files that you can view in the `eog` window.

### View several files side by side in one single window

You can install `feh`

```
sudo apt install feh
```

and use it to make a montage, which means that you can view several files in the same window.

**Examples**

```
feh --limit-height 700 --limit-width 1300 --montage --thumb-height 300 --thumb-width 600 file1.png file2.png file3.png file4.png

feh --fullscreen --montage --thumb-height 600 --thumb-width 800 Pictures/
```

In the fullscreen example you can zoom with the up/down arrows and then 'pull' the picture-montage with the mouse (grab with the left button and move) to scroll the zoomed pictures. Notice that the resolution depends on the thumb-height and thumb-width.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mulimg_viewer. (This is my repository).

Mulimg viewer is a multi-image viewer that can open multiple images in one interface, which is convenient for image comparison and image stitching.

Mulimg_viewer supports sequential and parallel mode to display image.

Mulimg_viewer is implemented in python and currently provides Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 versions.

Future: The parallel zoom function of the picture is being realized and I believe it will be released soon.

GitHub: https://github.com/nachifur/Mulimg_viewer

Wiki: https://github.com/nachifur/Mulimg_viewer/wiki

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Y3n.jpg)

Comment: Is this your repository? If so, please do [edit] to mention that in the post. We have a rather strict policy on self-promotion here and linking to your own project without disclosing affiliation could lead to posts being deleted.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reminder. I have modified it, is it okay now?

Comment: Yes thanks, that's perfect :) Thank you very much for sharing your work. You might like to add installation instructions and/or even better a brief step-by-step on how to do what the question asks for, if you can fit it in.